# Error while using Fred's ImageMagick Scripts with Cygwin/ImageMagick Display under Windows

Tags: cygwin, imagemagick

There are already a lot of threads about Fred's Scripts on Windows, but not quite what I was looking for.
I'm using W10 Pro with the latest Cygwin and ImageMagick Display.
So here's my problem: I followed the instructions on http://im.snibgo.com/cygwin.htm as good as I can.

Now when I start Cygwin and go to cygdrive/c/users/myname/Pictures/ and type for example:

```
$ textcleaner sample.png out_sample.png -g
```

it gives me:

```
Unzulässiger Parameter - configure
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: Zeile 400: [: : Ganzzähliger Ausdruck erwartet.
Unzulässiger Parameter - configure
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: Zeile 417: [: : Ganzzähliger Ausdruck erwartet.
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: Zeile 423: [: : Ganzzähliger Ausdruck erwartet.
Unzulässiger Parameter - sample.png
--- FILE sample.png NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE ---
```

and here in English (as good as I could):

```
undue parameter - configure
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: line 400: [: : integer expression expected.
undue parameter - configure
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: line 417: [: : integer expression expected.
/cygdrive/c/Scripts/textcleaner: line 423: [: : integer expression expected.
undue parameter - sample.png
--- FILE sample.png NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE ---
```

I really don't know anything about bash, my goal is an OCR application for Windows and i expected this script to help me get better results from 'my' engine.

Can anybody help me here? Am I missing some crucial information for you? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you have the correct build of Windows 10 I believe you can activate a Linux bash shell. It might be worth giving that a go?

Comment: That would be one way in fact, but the server for the app runs on W7 and I can't change that (rented). So a way to make it work on my PC first would be great.

Comment: what is the output of `/usr/bin/identify sample.png` ?

Comment: I can find and go into `/usr/bin` but it cant find identify:  `-bash cd: identify: No such file or directory` Or did I do something wrong? Please be more specific in that case. Thank you!

Comment: /usr/bin/identify is part of the cygwin package ImageMagick. If you are missing it, you have not installed the cygwin version of ImageMagick. As textcleaner is a bash script I suspect it will work better with it

Comment: Okay so I downloaded the ImageMagick package from their site and installed it with the cygwin console. But I still get the same errors. I'm a little bit frustrated tbh. Is there another way except Cygwin to run a bash script on windows? Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: `textcleaner -g sample.png out_sample.png` works fine for me.

Comment: Hey, quick update: I deleted all the Cygwin files from my PC and did it all over again. Now it works (idk why or what's different, did everything the same way like I did in the first place imo). The bash scripts runs like a charm, thanks for the help guys! :)

Comment: You have the wrong syntax. All arguments must come before the input and output images.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same errors. I found out that if you open the textcleaner.sh script and replace all occurrences of convert with magick, the script starts working in Windows.

The work done by convert is handled by magick.exe which can be found in the location where you installed ImageMagick. Make sure that you have all the relevant paths added.

Hope it helps.